# Monitor azure with nagios and odbc-freetds

Tags: azure, odbc, azure-sql-database, nagios, freetds

I want to monitor Azure Paas database with Nagios. I'm using this plugin available at https://github.com/MsOpenTech/WaMo

When I try to check database:
./check_azure_sql.py  -u  -p  -d  -k top5queries

I get this error message:

> ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
>   Error connecting to database

All dependencies are installed (list in GitHub plugin site).

Here you can see my /etc/odbcinst.ini:

```html
[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log

[FreeTDS]
Description = ODBC For TDS
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount = 1
```

Here you can see my /etc/freetds/freetds.conf:

```html
#   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
#
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same
# name is found in the installation directory.
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings,
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 4.2

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 10
;       connect timeout = 10

        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
        text size = 64512

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
        host = symachine.domain.com
        port = 5000
        tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer70]
        host = ntmachine.domain.com
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.0
```

And my /etc/odbc.ini is empty.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I am trying to understand as to what exactly are you trying to do? If you are essentially trying to connect to Azure SQL DB/SQL Server using python there is a much simpler way(use pymmsql)

Comment: Hello meet-bhagdev, to do simple, i'm trying to monitor Sql database Azure Paas with nagios. It's not me that is written the plugin available at https://github.com/MsOpenTech/WaMo. For a nagios admin, i only need to execute the command ./check_azure_sql.py -u (username) -p (password) -d (database) -k (key) (check_azure_sql.py written in python) from debian linux cli. So when i execute the command above i get the error message  ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') Error connecting to database. Than'ks for your help guy's.

Answer (score 0):

bhagdev, to do simple, i'm trying to monitor Sql database Azure Paas with nagios.

It's not me that is written the plugin available at github.com/MsOpenTech/WaMo. For a nagios admin, i only need to execute the command ./check_azure_sql.py -u (username) -p (password) -d (database) -k (key) (check_azure_sql.py written in python) from debian linux cli.

So when i execute the command above i get the error message :

('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') Error connecting to database.

Than'ks for your help guy's

Comment: Hi Kevin,Thanks for the question. What OS are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using "Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS" with Nagios® Core™ 4.0.7

Comment: Hi Kevin, seems like the plugin has an issue. You might have to work with the authors on that. If you want to connect to Azure SQL DB on your ubuntu using python there is an easy way out : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-python-simple-ubuntu-linux/